# LARAVEL: Need something like a "->with()", but working without foreingKey

Tags: laravel, function, eloquent

I have This:

```php
class Player extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'player_name',
        'player_level',
        'player_day'
    ];

    public function animals()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Animal::class);
    }

    public function test()
    {
        return "z";
    }
}
```

When I want to access this information, what I do is:

```
$player = Player::with('animals')->findOrFail($id);
```

This works perfect.

But i wanna access what test() returns in the same eloquentOrder, like this:

```
$player = Player::with('animals', 'test')->findOrFail($id);
```

But it fails, because:

```
"message": "Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on string",
```

how can i do that?

Comment: P.D. - i don't wanna $player->test() i need it as as "column"

Comment: i need it just in one line order

Comment: then create an accessor instead of the regular method

Comment: mm... never heared about accessor.. im gona check this, ty

Comment: OK IT WORKS. and that what EXACTLY what i WANT - LOVE U

Comment: For future reference, `->with()` will only work for Relationship functions, i.e. anything that uses `$this->belongsTo()`, `$this->hasMany()`, `$this->belongsToMany()`, etc. Your `test()` function was not using any of those, so `->with('test')` will trigger that error. Also, `->test` (no `()`) would be a property, not a "column", while `->test()` (with `()`) would be a method; correct terminology can definitely help when asking questions 